# Passing table join results to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following ASP.Net MVC controller action which joins 2 tables:-

```
public ActionResult PersonNotes()
{
    var model = db.Notes
        .Join(db.People, p => p.NotesListId, n => n.NotesListId, 
            ((note, person) => new { note, person })).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

And in my view I have the following model declaration:-

```
@model IEnumerable<Tuple<Models.Note, Models.Person>>
```

I get the following error:-

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousTypef`2[Models.Note,Models.Person]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Tuple`2[Models.Note,Models.Person]]'.
```

I realise that I can just use a ViewModel and a Select() within my join, but it would far more convenient to just have access to all items without having to create a ViewModel.

What is the correct declaration in my view, or is what I am trying to achieve not possible this way?

Comment: The @Romoku answer is technically correct but it is better to have concretely typed view models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous object and your view wants a model with a `Tuple`. [The anonymous type is generated by the compiler and is not available at the source code level.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Try changing your statement to create an `IEnumerable<Tuple<Models.Note, Models.Person>>` with `Tuple.Create`:

```
var model = db.Notes
    .Join(db.People, p => p.NotesListId, n => n.NotesListId, 
        ((note, person) => Tuple.Create(note, person))).ToList();
```

See [`Tuple.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx).

If you are using Linq to Entities or Entity Framework then you will need to either iterate the `IQueryable` into a `Tuple` or use a `class`.

```
var model = db.Notes
    .Join(db.People, p => p.NotesListId, n => n.NotesListId, 
        ((note, person) => new { note, person }))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.note, x.person))
    .ToList();
```

Or

Create a `class` to hold the `Person` and `Note`.

```
public class PersonNote
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

Change the statement to use the new `PersonNote`.

```
var model = db.Notes
    .Join(db.People, p => p.NotesListId, n => n.NotesListId, 
        ((note, person) => new PersonNote { Note = note, Person = person }))
    .ToList();
```

Change the model.

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonNote>
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but very grateful for your response. Are tuple members always referenced as Item1, Item2... or can I overide this with more meaningful names?

Comment: I am now getting the following error in my query. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Tuple`2[Models.Note,Models.Person] Create[Note,Person](Models.Note, Models.Person)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ah if you're using Linq to Entities then you will need to make a class or use an additional select. Let me update my example for you.